# Does an infinite amount of randomly chosen numbers within a definite interval form a connected space?

Tags: continuity, connectedness, random, path-connected

*This is my own question but I assume it has been asked before; I just have not found where. I am curious of the answer but I don't know how to approach solving it. I would appreciate it if someone could help me out with tags because I don't have any experience with this area in math. Also, please let me know if I misued the words "connected space." I was originally going to use "continuous" but saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362851/is-there-such-thing-as-a-continuous-set) and changed it.*

This is my original question

> Can any continuous function be represented by infinite polynomial interpolation of random points in a definite interval?

Which I simplified to

> Is every point on a line of definite length covered after infinitely many points are placed on it?

Which I realized is equivalent to

> Is a continuous line formed by an infinite amount of points on the x-axis contained in a definite interval?

Which I simplified down to the question of this post.

Depending on the answers to this question, I plan to ask my original question along with some follow-ups about extending it to an infinite interval and to parametric functions.

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  As I read it, $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is a counter-example.  There are infinitely many rational numbers between $0$ and $1$, but these numbers do not cover the interval.  But you are also throwing around the idea of continuity, which is a bit of confusion.

Comment: "Infinite" isn't the right notion here.  No countably infinite set of points can form a connected subinterval of the line, for example.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I think I see what you are saying. I had forgotten about countably  vs uncountably infinite sets when I wrote the question. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @DylanLevine My comment is not an answer.  It is a question, seeking clarification about what the question is actually asking (and giving you an opportunity to edit the question in order to clarify).  If, indeed, the question boils down to the distinction between countable and uncountable, I suspect that it has already been asked-and-answered on the site before.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I feel like the questions "Is a continuous line formed by an infinite amount of points on the x-axis contained in a definite interval?" and "Is every point on a line of definite length covered after infinitely many points are placed on it?" have the same problem as the one I asked. Do they not?